# minimum_should_match parameter in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We would like to find an alternative of Elasticsearch: minimum_should_match in Azure Search

Elasticsearch query example:

```
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [{...}],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "minimum_should_match" : "45",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [{...}],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "minimum_should_match" : "38",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [{...}],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "minimum_should_match" : "29",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
```

We successfully transformed ES query to Azure Search one, except for minimum_should_match parameter. Any suggestions?

Comment: The tag #elasticsearch is confusing as the `minimum_should_match` parameter is fully supported by the official Elasticsearch distributions from Elastic. Your question is specific to Microsoft's implementation of Azure search (which is based on Elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks @DanielSchneiter ! removed from the tag list

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Cognitive Search does not currently expose Elasticsearch's `minimum_should_match` to the user, and it is not being worked on right now. If there is enough customer demand down the line, we will add it to our roadmap.